# React animations error #119

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

estoy tratando de hacer uso de la libreria [ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) que explican en la documentación oficial de React. Estoy copiando este [código](https://jsfiddle.net/n5Luz6ym/) para probar. Pero aún así no funciona. Tengo este error en la consola:

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #119; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=119 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

Esos "Helpul" warnings se pueden leer [acá](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=119).

Mis archivos js importados son solamente estos:

```
<script src="{% static "js/react.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/react-dom.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/react-with-addons.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/babel.min.js" %}"></script>  <!-- Para compilar el JSX en ambientes non Node, compila el codigo de abajo-->
<script src="{% static "js/pruebaAnimacion.js" %}" type="text/babel"></script>
```

No entiendo cual es el problema. En fiddle funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la descripción completa del error dice:

> ... You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method, **or you have multiple copies of React**

Viendo tu código y los `scripts` que cargas, se ve que **estas cargando dos copias de `React`** (eg: `react.min.js` y `react-with-addons.min.js`)

Aquí debajo te dejo una copia funcional de ejemplo en `codepen`

```html
<style>
  .example-enter {
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: font-size 1s ease-out;
  }

  .example-enter.example-enter-active {
    font-size: 1em;
  }

  .example-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
  }

  .example-leave.example-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.01;
  }

  .example-appear {
    opacity: 0.01;
    transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
  }

  .example-appear.example-appear-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
</style>

<div id="foo"></div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.18.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="//fb.me/react-with-addons-0.14.7.js"></script>
<script src="//fb.me/react-dom-0.14.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  var Foo = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {items: ['Start from here']}
    },
    saveAndContinue: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({items: this.state.items.concat([Date.now()])});
    },
    render: function() {
      return (

        <React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="example" 
          transitionAppear={true}
          className='button-row'
          component='ul'
          >
          {this.state.items.map(function(item) {
              return <li><a key={item} href="#" className="button" onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>{item}</a></li>
          }, this)}
        </React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup>

      )
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById('foo')); 
</script>
```

Comment: No se como agradecerte! Había probado borrando el react.min.js, pero me quedaba el with-addons.min.js abajo del reactDom.min.js y generaba problemas. Puse todo en el orden que utilizaste vos y salió andando perfecto! Gracias!